# Steam OpenID URL Blocked

Tags: openid, steam

Just wondering how I could remove [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtrUO.png) message?

I am using the Steam OpenID API, and have had no issues using it. However, this message is really bugging me, and i'm worried it's going to scare away new users.

Now, i'm assuming this message is appearing because I am using a free `.tk` domain - for testing purposes. I am able to login, by pressing the "continue anyway" button at the bottom of the screenshot above.

Am I right? If so, which domains can I use which are not blocked? I don't mind paying $30 for one, as long as the message doesn't appear.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This sounds like a Steam support question

Comment: Hi, did you manage to resolve this? I'm facing the same issue right now with a project :P

Comment: @LanfeaR Which domain extension are you using?